# Error: Module did not self register

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile, npm-install

I have the exact same error which says

```
at bindings (/node_modules/pg-native/node_modules/libpq/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
```

This might seem similar to:
[Error: Module did not self-register.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964310/error-module-did-not-self-register/35134624#35134624)
but the difference being, I am using docker to build images, so it will not be possible for me to go back and remove node_modules and perform npm install again for every container.
Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Did you updated your node or npm version?

Comment: Yes, I was using the latest versions. I found a fix by doing `npm rebuild`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error when I ran docker-compose. Also, in my docker-compose I was mounting the current folder. To fix this issue I rebuilt my node modules with `npm rebuild`.

Comment: Although docker appeared to make your problem distinct, the canonical thread [Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486891/uncaught-error-module-did-not-self-register), has the same [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28859693/6243352), `npm rebuild`. For future visitors, it may be a good idea to visit that thread if this doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of Docker is that it should be easy to upgrade your images and replace your containers. If you have a bunch of Node apps which all start from the same image:

```
FROM node
```

Then you just need to rebuild your images and they will use the latest version of the Node base image (which currently has NPM `3.10.3`). In a non-production environment, just stop your container and run a new one from the new image. In production, look at [rolling upgrades in swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/).

Ideally you should be working towards an automated workflow where you commit a change, that builds a new image and replaces your running container. You shouldn't need to do any maintenance on running containers - they are meant to be disposable.

Comment: Thanks Elton. I figured the solution was to do a rebuild after installing node with `npm rebuild` and that fixed the errors.