# (Node )Error: Module did not self-register

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Getting this error while lifting the serve: sails lift

```
Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
```

Comment: likely module compiled for older version of node. Move `./node_modules` to backup and do `npm install` again

Comment: you could try **rm -r node_modules** then **npm install**

Comment: Have you updated Node? Either manually or via `n` or `nvm`?

Comment: updated node version via npm..,i remove the files inside the node modules folder and run npm install but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486891/uncaught-error-module-did-not-self-register)