# Bindings Module did not self-register

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having this problem when I try to run my node.js app. I have tried to remove my node_modules folder and then npm install but that doesn't work. Any idea?

Thanks!

This is the error :

```
node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
        ^

Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at bindings (/.../.../react-rpi/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.../.../react-rpi/node_modules/epoll/epoll.js:1:99)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486891/uncaught-error-module-did-not-self-register ?

Comment: Are you actually running this on a Linux system or a different platform (e.g. OS X or BSD)?

Comment: I'm running on OS X. Npm rebuild didn't work for me neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are trying to run a native module that did not compile for your architecture / peripherals.

Please comment those packages out (`raspberry-gpio`, `libusb` and others) and try to work it out from there.