# Meteor: Error: Module did not self-register

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to deploy the [Wekan](https://github.com/wekan/wekan) trello clone from source, but I'm having a hard time. I can run the source by simply running `meteor -p 80`, but I want to properly deploy it, so I (successfully) built the source into a bundle. I then tried running it using `node main.js`, but that fails with the error below.

I followed the advice from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28859693/1650012) of running `npm rebuild` and I also tried `rm -r node_modules` and another `npm install` before running `node main.js` again, but it again ends in the error below.

Does anybody know what else I can try to fix this?

```
$ node main.js
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at Module.Mp.load (/root/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
/root/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                        throw(ex);
                        ^

Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at Module.Mp.load (/root/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (/root/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at Module.Mp.load (/root/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Comment: Any updated on this? suffering exactly the same for keban

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Looking now into this: https://github.com/wekan/wekan/issues/670