# ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED When trying to make a node native addon

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I was attempting to make a node native addon and `node-gyp configure build` worked fine, when i required the test addon in a javascript file and ran it normally with `node main` it then gives the error `Error: Module did not self register, code: ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED` here is my code so far:

binding.gyp

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "hello",
            "source": ["hello.cc"]
        }
    ]
}
```

hello.cc

```
#include <node/node.h>
#include <node/v8.h>

using namespace v8;

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>&args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world").ToLocalChecked());
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize);
```

main.js

```
const hello = require("./build/Release/hello");
console.log(hello.hello())
```

How do i fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486891/uncaught-error-module-did-not-self-register)

Answer (score 1):

You can check what version of node you are using
nvm ls (to list out the node versions)

try changing the node version to check and run the command again
nvm use version_number (to change the version)

Comment: This actually worked. This issue was coming when I was using Node v17 on a project which I started in Node v14. Just changing my local node version using nvm worked for me.